# csv->Oracle DB autoscheduled import

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cron, sql-insert

I have basic csv report that is produced by other team on a daily basis, each report has 50k rows, those reports are saved on sharedrive everyday. And I have Oracle DB.

I need to create autoscheduled process (or at least less manual) to import those csv reports to Oracle DB. What solution would you recommend for it?

I did not find such solution in SQL Developer, since it is upload from file and not a query. I was thinking about python cron script, that will autoran on a daily basis and transform csv report to txt with needed SQL syntax (insert into...) and then python will connect to Oracle DB and will ran  txt file as SQL command and insert data.
But this looks complicated.

Maybe you know other solution that you would recommend yo use?

Comment: read up on oracle external tables and dbms_scheduler

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an [external table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-external-tables-concepts.html#GUID-44323E01-7D72-45EC-915A-99E596769D9E) to allow you to access the content of the CSV as if it were a regular table. This assumes the file name does not change day-to-day.
2. Create a [scheduled job](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/scheduling-jobs-with-oracle-scheduler.html#GUID-D41660D0-D88F-4D9F-8CC8-63D040EDC4E6) to import the data in that external table and do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

One common blocking issue that prevents using 'external tables' is that external tables require the data to be on the computer hosting the database.  Not everyone has access to those servers.  Or sometimes the external transfer of data to that machine + the data load to the DB is slower than doing a direct path load from the remote machine.

SQL*Loader with direct path load may be an option: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144  This will be faster than Python.

If you do want to use Python, then read the cx_Oracle manual [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).  There is an example of reading from a CSV file.